# How to implement square bracket notation programmatically?

Tags: javascript

Given the following data set

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "zoro",
    specie: "dog",
    age: 3,
    size: "big",
    location: {
      city: "city 1",
      town: "city 1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "nami",
    specie: "dog",
    age: 5,
    size: "small",
    location: {
      city: "city 1",
      town: "city 11",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "ocho",
    specie: "cat",
    age: 9,
    size: "small",
    location: {
      city: "city x",
      town: "city x",
    },
  },
];
```

I'm trying to get summaries of an array of objects via some of its properties. The detail is that some values of those properties are other objects for example `location`

In order to obtain the summary I did the following

```
function tally(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((previous, current) => {
      previous[current[key]] = (previous[current[key]] || 0) + 1;

    return previous;
  }, {});
}
```

In this way I get the following results

```
const specieTally = tally(data, "specie"); // { dog: 2, cat: 1 }
const ageTally = tally(data, "age"); // { '3': 1, '5': 1, '9': 1 }
const sizeTally = tally(data, "size"); // { big: 1, small: 2 }
const locationTally = tally(data, "location.city"); // { undefined: 3 }
```

As you can see the result of `locationTally` is not correct. In order to move forward I perform a manual verification of this possible scenario. Example:

```
function tally(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((previous, current) => {
    if (key === "location.city") {
      previous[current["location"]["city"]] = (previous[current["location"]["city"]] || 0) + 1;
    } else {
      previous[current[key]] = (previous[current[key]] || 0) + 1;
    }

    return previous;
  }, {});
}
```

Thus, the output is the following:

```
const locationTally = tally(data, "location.city"); // { 'city 1': 2, 'city x': 1 }
```

This temporarily solves but I would like to know how programmatically the same result could be obtained

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#get this get functon mght help

Comment: How about splitting your key on `.` and iterating through the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "zoro",
        specie: "dog",
        age: 3,
        size: "big",
        location: {
          city: "city 1",
          town: "city 1",
        },
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "nami",
        specie: "dog",
        age: 5,
        size: "small",
        location: {
          city: "city 1",
          town: "city 11",
        },
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "ocho",
        specie: "cat",
        age: 9,
        size: "small",
        location: {
          city: "city x",
          town: "city x",
        },
      },
    ];
    
    function tally(array, key) {
      return array.reduce((previous, current) => {
        if (key.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
          let keys = key.split('.');
          previous[getNestedValue(current, keys)] = (previous[getNestedValue(current, keys)] || 0) + 1;
        } else {
          previous[current[key]] = (previous[current[key]] || 0) + 1;
        }
        return previous;
      }, {});
    }
    
    function getNestedValue(element, keys) {
       let value = element;
       keys.forEach(key => {
          value = value[key];
       })
       return value;
    }
    
    const locationTally = tally(data, "location.city");
    console.log(locationTally);
```

Here, we split the key by a dot character, if present, and then we get the exact nested value, using a function, which loops over the splitted the keys, and go deeper in each iteration, until it reaches the end. You might wanna add appropriate null checks, however.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to resolve the key, with an array reduce

```js
const data =
  [{id:1,name:'zoro',specie:'dog',age:3,size:'big',location:{city:'city 1',town:'city 1'}},{id:2,name:'nami',specie:'dog',age:5,size:'small',location:{city:'city 1',town:'city 11'}},{id:3,name:'ocho',specie:'cat',age:9,size:'small',location:{city:'city x',town:'city x'}}]

, tally = 
  (arr, key) => arr.reduce((acc, arrElm) => 
    {
    let ref = key.split('.').reduce((o,k) => o[k], arrElm)
    acc[ref] = (acc[ref] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
    }
    , {})

, specieTally   = tally( data, 'specie'  )       // { dog: 2, cat: 1          }
, ageTally      = tally( data, 'age'       )     // { '3': 1, '5': 1, '9': 1  }
, sizeTally     = tally( data, 'size'        )   // { big: 1, small: 2        }
, locationTally = tally( data, 'location.city' ) // { 'city 1': 2, 'city x': 1 }
  ;

console.log ('specieTally:', specieTally, '\nageTally:', ageTally, '\nsizeTally:', sizeTally, '\nlocationTally:', locationTally  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```